# Android json send data

Tags: java, android, json, post

I'm trying to send json (java Android):
This is full code.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com");
try {
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "qwerty"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123457"));
  HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
  httppost.setEntity(entity);
  // Headers
  httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httppost);
  responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

  System.out.println(responseString);
  return responseString;

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("error");
  return "";
}
```

Server php code:

```
<?php
  $response[] = array(
    'postcount' => count($_POST), // Get count $_POST
    'get' => count($_GET),
    'request' => count($_REQUEST)
  );

  echo json_encode($response);
?>

System.out.println(request) - // And i get [{"postcount":null,"get":null,"request":null}]
```

Request send successfull, but parameters miss.
Help please :)

Comment: but what is ur aim? what u want ? where r u stucked? plz mentoin

Comment: @AndroidDev I want send request with parameters.

Comment: u dont want to send request with params?

Comment: In this code Request has been successfully sent. But without parameters.

Comment: ok tell me what u r expection from output and what u r giving to url? u want get or post method?

Comment: I want send login and password from android phone, and get from server result success or not success

Comment: ok fine , where u r stucked now?

Comment: I'm sending the request. Request is successful. Parameters do not go (login, password). 
On the server, check the request comes without parameters (login, password).

Comment: I want **send parameters** :D

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Comment: did u solved the issue?